# Substitute an expression iteratively

Tags: expression-manipulation

I have defined this function

```
replaceIteratively[expr_, x_, list_] := Module[{n = 0}, expr /. x :> (n++; list[[n]])]
```

which does the following job

```
replaceIteratively[h[a]h[b]h[c]h[d],h,{h1,h2,h3,h4}]
(*Out: h1[a] h2[b] h3[c] h4[d]*)
replaceIteratively[h[a]h[b]h[c],h,{h1,h2,h3}]
(*Out: h1[a] h2[b] h3[c]*)
replaceIteratively[h[a]h[b]h[c,d],h,{h1,h2,h3}]
(*Out: h1[a] h2[b] h3[c,d]*)
```

However, it does not work when applied to the expression `h*h*h*h`

```
replaceIteratively[h*h*h*h,h,{h1,h2,h3,h4}]
(*Out: h1^4*)
```

I would like it to return `h1 h2 h3 h4`

How can I modify this function such that it works with expressions like `Power[h,4]`?

Answer (score 3):

```
Clear["Global`*"]

replaceIteratively[expr_, x_, list_] := Module[{n = 1, expr2},
  expr2 = 
   expr /. Power[y_, n_Integer] :> 
     Inactive[Times] @@ ConstantArray[y, n];
  (expr2 /. x :> list[[n++]]) // Activate]

replaceIteratively[h[a] h[b] h[c] h[d], h, {h1, h2, h3, h4}]

(* h1[a] h2[b] h3[c] h4[d] *)

replaceIteratively[h[a] h[b] h[c, d], h, {h1, h2, h3}]

(* h1[a] h2[b] h3[c, d] *)

replaceIteratively[h*h*h*h, h, {h1, h2, h3, h4}]

(* h1 h2 h3 h4 *)

replaceIteratively[h[]*h[]*h[]*h[], h, {h1, h2, h3, h4}]

(* h1[] h2[] h3[] h4[] *)
```

Comment: Thanks. Is there a way to make it work also with h[]*h[]*h[]*h[]? The idea is that I only want to specify the Head as the argument `x_`

Comment: Modified to handle that case

Comment: While upvoting rapidly is fine, you should not accept an answer so rapidly. An accepted answer tends to discourage others from offering alternative solutions. Give the community some time and you might get a better answer.

Comment: Thanks for your advice. I unaccepted the answer. I will wait a few days

Answer (score 2):

The following small modification should work:

```
ClearAll@replaceIteratively
SetAttributes[replaceIteratively, HoldFirst]
replaceIteratively[expr_, x_, list_] := Module[{n = 0}, Hold[expr] /. x :> (n++; list[[n]])] // ReleaseHold
```

Then:

```
replaceIteratively[h[a] h[b] h[c] h[d], h, {h1, h2, h3, h4}]
replaceIteratively[h[a] h[b] h[c, d], h, {h1, h2, h3}]
replaceIteratively[h*h*h*h, h, {h1, h2, h3, h4}]
(* h1[a] h2[b] h3[c] h4[d]
   h1[a] h2[b] h3[c, d]
   h1 h2 h3 h4 *)
```

If you don't want general functionality and really just want to iterate the head name, you can do

```
replaceIteratively[expr_, x_] := Module[{n = 1}, Hold[expr] /. x :> Symbol@StringJoin[ToString@x, ToString@n++]] // ReleaseHold
```

and so

```
replaceIteratively[h[a] h[b] h[c] h[d], h]
replaceIteratively[h[a] h[b] h[c, d], h]
replaceIteratively[h*h*h*h, h]
replaceIteratively[h[] h[] h[] h[], h]
(* h1[a] h2[b] h3[c] h4[d]
   h1[a] h2[b] h3[c, d]
   h1 h2 h3 h4
   h1[] h2[] h3[] h4[]
*)
```

This will of course work with nested expressions:

```
replaceIteratively[h[h[h h, h[h[b]]]] h[c, d], h]
(* h1[h2[h3 h4, h5[h6[b]]]] h7[c, d] *)
```